# Плагин/модуль/виджет чтобы выводить последние фото Instagram на сайте?

Tags: javascript, api, joomla, cms, instagram

Нужно на странице выводить последние 5 фото с инстаграма. Сайт на Джумла. Какое самое лучшее решение? Желательно чтобы дизайном блока можно было играть(но необязательно).

Comment: На wix.com есть подобная вещь, называется виджет "Instagram feed", может где ещё она есть, или вы сможете код оттуда взять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам гибкое решение для любого сайта.

```js
var userFeed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId: '623597756',
    clientId: '02b47e1b98ce4f04adc271ffbd26611d',
    accessToken: '623597756.02b47e1.3dbf3cb6dc3f4dccbc5b1b5ae8c74a72',
    resolution: 'standard_resolution',
    template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" id="{{id}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    limit: 5,
    links: false
  });
  userFeed.run();
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #333;
}

#instafeed {
  width: 100%;
}
#instafeed a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 580px) {
  #instafeed a {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
#instafeed a img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://matthewelsom.com/assets/js/libs/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<div id="instafeed"></div>
```

Скрипт настраивается так как вам нужно. Вот [инструкция](https://elfsight.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-get-instagram-access-token/) по получению clientId и accessToken. Эти данные потребуются в любом случае.

[Источник](http://codepen.io/matthewelsom/pen/zrrrLN)

Comment: instagram не дал мне client secret. только client id выдал. Это нормально?

Comment: теперь при получении токена проблема. Ввожу ключи и дает такую страницу -

Comment: {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Redirect URI does not match registered redirect URI"}

Comment: это содержимое страницы

Comment: все исправил. спасибо

Comment: все работает. Но почему то если вставляю свой id инстаграма(или любой другой) туда, то не работает.                                                                                     Uncaught Error: Error from Instagram: this user does not exist                                              id верный вставляю.

Comment: Вы заменяете только userId?

Comment: уже разобрался во всем, спасибо. Решение супер. Только link не получается использовать. Джумла почему воспринимает его как не ссылку и добавляет в начале домен сайта. Можно добавить перед link htttp. Тогда как ссылку воспринимает, но становится два http в ссылке.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать готовое решение для `Joomla`. Данное расширение можете скачать [ТУТ](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/social-web/social-media/powr-instagram-feed/)

или же использовать виджет `Instagram`, документацию можете прочитать [ТУТ](https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/)

Comment: спасибо за попощь, но Джумла плагин этот ужасное решение, никому не советую пробовать, долго настаивать и платный(рекламу не убрать просто так там)